# After indexing file how to extract properties of file such as:-file type,name etc. by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika

I had indexed the document and I am able to search content of document.
But I want to find the type of document is indexed, author of document , name of document, size of document basically properties of file. 
How it can be achieved with the help of elasticsearch.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use elastic search head to take a look at the index tika generated in ElasticSearch for you

http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/

Then you can search on those fields by using queries like author:Lav (assuming you found a field named author in your index)